# Tags for movies with the same name and remakes?

Tags: discussion

There are several movies that share the same title. Sometimes they are completely different movies and not remakes. How should we tag these?

[foo-1950](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foo-1950) and [foo-2010](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foo-2010)?

Also, the series title may be the name of an individual movie. For instance, [starwars](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starwars) could refer to episode 4, or the entire series. What to do here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rules for multiple media using the same name](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1427/rules-for-multiple-media-using-the-same-name)

Answer (score 3):

I am still unconvinced that individual movies should be tagged at all, but have been led to believe that little used tags will eventually disappear automatically - so I guess this doesn't matter.

So, to answer your question, the easy part is the year.  I would propose following your 'year' convention, which seems pretty simple for example:

[ladykillers-1955](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ladykillers-1955) and [ladykillers-2004](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ladykillers-2004)

For the question about series, perhaps encourage a series suffix:

[jamesbond-series](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jamesbond-series) [starwars-series](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starwars-series)