# Title tag for only one (first) question about the movie?

Tags: support, tags

I just posted (and self-answered) a [question about the movie Magallanes](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/78673/magallanes-translation-from-quechua).

There <strike>is</strike> was [nothing on the site yet about that movie](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=magallanes).

**Does one question about a title justify creating a new tag for it?** <sup>*</sup>

[This question](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1733/do-you-think-its-time-for-a-change-in-the-way-we-use-tags) seems to indicate 'yes'.

[This answer](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24/20086) suggest that little-used tags disappear automatically, which would make the question irrelevant. I know this from other SE sites, but maybe Movies.SE works differently?

<sup>* Not that I can do that, I currenty have less than 300 rep.</sup>

Comment: Yes, Movies.SE *does* work differently, for exactly the reason that, yes, every film that has a question gets a tag.